# From Berry's phase to artificial Gauge potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, yang-mills, berry-pancharatnam-phase

How a nonzero [geometric phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_phase) in a loop is used to generate artificial gauge potentials? If possible, can you also tell how to generate the non-abelian artificial gauge potentials.

Comment: Would you please tell us where you encountered this notion, and what is your background. How it's written your question seems to be a homework you ask us to solve... Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FraSchelle : I am sorry- I realize I wrote it in a wrong way. I have the answer to this question. I am basically talking about optical lattices where different net phases can be generated in different plaquettes of the lattice using lasers with different phases and directions and thus arbitrary potentials can be generated.